# Git get commit id in the original repository instead of the one in the forked repo

Tags: git, github

On Github, I forked a repo and made some changes. After committing the changes to my **forked repo**, I want to initiate a PR so that my changes can be applied in the original repo. The owner of this repo request every PR to label itself with **its commit id**.

My problem is: how can I get the commit id in the **original repo** instead of in my forked repo?

Comment: Why "the owner of this repo request every PR to label itself with its commit id"? Why "the owner of this repo" require it? This can be managed by machine only, not needed by human. This is a strange question, maybe an X-Y question.

Comment: Besides, there is no difference between commit id from forked repo and original repo.